# How do I know when I need a dedicated DSP chip?

Tags: signal-processing, microcontroller

When designing an embedded system, how can I tell in general when the floating point processing required will be too much for a standard microcontroller?

In case anyone is curious, the system I am designing is a Kalman filter and some motor control. However, I am looking for an engineering methodology for the general case.

Comment: you build it and see what happens? Or you analyse your design and see if its processing requirements are below what your controller can deliver. Since you've provided no details at ALL about your system, we can't really help you.

Comment: Usually you would do some basic analysis of the algorithm you are using (how many arithmetic operations per sample etc), then plug in some numbers like sample rate etc. Also you might consider separately whether you need any of the special features of a DSP, e.g. modulo addressing, bit reversed addressing, fixed point, built-in I/O, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general case on finding out whether the given processor can solve your problem, is to estimate the number of floating-point operations that have to be run per second, and then comparing it to what the processor can do.

This ideal case will be affected by memory-access times, I/O-interrupts, etc. In practise, you'll have to run it (although you don't want to hear that).

For the Kalman filter case:
1. Know the sample rate, the size of the state variable and the measurement-variable.
2. The complexity of the Kalman filter is dominated by the matrix inversion and multiple matrix multiplications. ([O(d^3)](http://stat.columbia.edu/~liam/research/pubs/fast-low-rank-kalman.pdf), d: size of state variable, or the Information Filter (inverse problem): O(z^3), z: size of measurement-vector) On-line or in books you'll find in-detail analysis of the operations required for Kalman Filters.
3. Find out what *actual* operations are run in the algorithms and add the number of operations required for each part of the algorithm.

The analysis is essentially the same for a general microcontroller or a DSP, except that some things come for free on the DSP.

Comment: IAR's EWARM has a simulator that you can compile & run your code in. You can then run the function profiler to give you total number of instructions for it. It's a good resource to use for estimating CPU requirements for ARM.